# What is a good area to head to in Lisbon's "Parque Florestal de Monsanto"?

Tags: portugal, lisbon, parks-and-gardens

I'd like to visit the "Parque Florestal de Monsanto" in Lisbon. But this is a very big (10 km2) park and I'm not not sure what area of the park to head to. Is there any area in the park in particular that is interesting to visit?

Comment: What are you looking for? "Parque florestal de Monsanto" is a green area and it's considered the city lung.  It has several very nice areas, and a few restaurants spreaded but I would hardly consider it a tourist destination.  Unless you want to chill out in a close by place. You might want to visit Sintra and "Serra de Sintra" if you're looking for nature, history and picturesque places. It's 40 min. aways from Lisbon by train.

Comment: Some people in my travel group are considering this as an option to have a day away from anything tourist-y, so not being a tourist destination is a good thing! Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you start with the "Centro de Interpretação de Monsanto " (Monsanto Interpretation Center). It is a building with a lot of information about this area (pictures of flora and fauna, maps, guides...) and from there you can decide where you want to go next.

Unfortunately, this page is not translated, but you can try to use an automatic translater:
http://www.cm-lisboa.pt/en/living-in/environment/monsanto-forest-park/espaco-monsanto
From this page you can also grab more ideas.

Public transportations in Monsanto are not good. Bike is a very good option (generally speaking of course).